# YAML or serialize() to store data in MySQL

Tags: php, database, serialization, yaml

I am trying store temporary data (such as cart products, session_data) in DB. And I choosed YAML for this instead of serialize() function. Because YAML data is easily readable by human and portable between programming languages.

Am I in trouble with YAML if I store my temprory data in database?

Comment: YAML is just another way to serialize data so in my opinion you're in no more trouble than if you would use the default serialization. Whether you should store serialized data at all is another question - sometimes it's justified and sometimes it just isn't.

Comment: Session data should get automatically serialized for you by the session handler when it calls your custom write function.  As for cart products, you should investigate a normalized format for storing cart products, e.g. a `cart` table and a `cart_items` table.

Comment: Or look into one of the many off-the-shelf tested and proven cart solutions already written and on the market, both for free and for cost -- don't fall into the NIH trap =)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use serialize for two reasons:

1. Its included in PHP by default.
2. What you put in is what you get out.

In regards to the second point. Serialize doesn't just convert to a string it records the type as well and PHP calls functions on objects so you can choose what to serialise and what do do with the data when you unserialise it.

See: [__sleep and __wake](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep)

It may not be easy to read directly from the database but it wouldn't take two minutes to write a script that could pull it out, unserialise it and do a print_r on the data to view what's stored.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't use YAML.  It's too format-dependent (Requiring new lines, whitespace, etc) and there's no native parser in PHP.  Instead, I'd use JSON for this.  It's trivial to handle natively, and is quite human readable (no as much as YAML, but much more so than serialized).  It's the best of both worlds.

But, with that said, you really should ask yourself the question as to why you want to store a serialized representation of a complex data structure in a field in the DB...  For most cases, it might be better to store a normalized representation of the data (so it's searchable easily, etc).  It's not "bad" to store serialized data, but it might not be optimal or the right choice depending on what you're trying to do.  It's generally far better than using an Entity-Attribute-Value store, but you need to really think about what you're doing to decide if it's the right thing.

Comment: +1 since JSON will address the inter-application portability he mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are escaping everything potentially dangerous i.e. user input and you are fine.

Comment: I'm currently working on a product that seriales temp data using serialize() to the db and it's just horrible to debug.