# serialize vs SQLite in Php

Tags: php, sqlite, serialization, storage

I want to store arrays in file. 
I triend csv (`fgetcsv`, `fputcsv`) but got tons of error related with locale. I cant continue using this.
I worked with serialize but editing is very hard. Also there is also a bug related `\r`.

I was looking a better and international way to store variables in file.

SQLite could solve. I wonder the performance of SQLite to compared with MySQL or basic serialize. Also if there is bugs I will come across.

Notes:

1. Arrays are 2 dimensional arrays. Same as `table->field`s in DB structure.
2. I don’t want to require additional program to install, portability is real problem, since people could install to any server, PHP, MySQL should be enough.
3. Why I don’t want to store in MySQL, because I will use this structure to serve cache. The final product I want to publish, could run without DB, for most of the time.
4. I wrote a basic structure using `fgetcsv` & `fputcvs`. There is bug! It strips some chars. That’s why I'm looking for alternative. I don’t want to invent whole wheel from beginning but PHP guys don’t understand programming: please review: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48507

Comment: In my opinion, if performance are not critic point, use XML serialization

Comment: if you are looking at sqlite, go use it.. its fast n light for your case.. it serves as a db too :)

Comment: If you have problems related to `\r` check the [auto_detect_line_endings setting](http://at2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings)

Comment: Can you give more information on the arrays you want to store? Is it a set, are both the keys and values relevant? Is it multidimensional?

Comment: You will never get proper answer, dude. Just because you fail to ask a proper question. No data example, no data size, no background, no context - nothing. you will get only answers as empty, as your question.

Comment: Sounds like CSV is a good option if you can get past your issues.

Can you maybe provide more information about what kind of issues you were running into with the encodings? I've worked quite a lot with different charsets/encodings, being from Iceland and all, and it can be troublesome, but nothing that can't be worked out.

What was the problem you had with the encodings, exactly?

Comment: It seems like you don't know what you want to do. Because there are so many easy ways to acheive this, it's almost like asking "how do I output data to the screen".

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a possibility for you is to cache your data as real PHP. The function [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) provides you with the PHP representation of data. It has some limitation, which [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) does not have when it comes to circular references, but on the other hand it is way easier to understand, because you already know the syntax.

Comment: Is there a var_import() function?

Comment: sims, you don't need one because the result of var_export is valid PHP code. You can simply include the file.

Answer (score 3):

May be `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` be good for you? Sqlite not good solution for multidimension arrays.

Comment: You don't store arrays directly into anything. If you encode to JSON, where do you store it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using YAML,

You can find the YAML website [here](http://www.yaml.org/) and you can find a small lib to handle YAML [here](http://components.symfony-project.org/yaml/)

Comment: He does not want dependencies. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888449/yaml-or-serialize-to-store-data-in-mysql 
What's the point of using YAML again?

Comment: No he doesn't want to install software(extensions) so the application is easily copied from server to server, which I have linked to a lib he can have reside in his application. YAML will work fine for this problem though serialize and json_encode are better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd need to serialize it. Then you can store it in anything you like. SQLite, MySQL, PGSQL, flat file, etc. Since you are serializing it, there shouldn't be a problem with locale.

**[edit]**

Of course you should serialize and PHP object you are trying to store. And you should not edit it directly via the storage medium. You should unserialize it and manipulate it via PHP.

**[edit]**

Since you have stated you do not want to use a database server, you have to use a flat file.

I would use SQLite. If you don't want to do that, you'll need to create your own file parser. You could store one object per file and identify the objects via the file name.

You'll have to think about user space though. If that is an issue, you can use sessions. This is quite common for caching data.

Just to reiterate, you need to serialize the data before using any method of storage. It's not serialize vs. SQLite. It's serilaize + SQLite. You need to serilaize it then insert it into and SQLite db or serialize the data and then store it in the session.

Caching data is nothing new. You are not breaking new ground. It's been done many times before.

Comment: Don't tell the poster that he shouldn't have a problem when he is reporting one. Also, the poster wanted to know differences between serializing an array and storing the array values in a database.

Comment: Perhaps you are having a problem reading or understand the problem. He tried to store an array in a CSV file. He said it *did* work with serialize, but it was difficult to edit. Of course you should serialize any PHP object you are trying to store. And you should not edit it directly via the storage medium. You should unserialize it and manipulate it via PHP. I thought that was obvious. I guess not, seeing as you don't understand either.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend use arrays as lists, sets or hashes, take a look at the key-value store [redis](http://redis.io/).

It's blazing fast, done for this kind of use, and there's a lot of PHP bindings.

Comment: He does not want dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like do_put() method [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/persephone/source/browse/sources/kernel_extensions/cache/abstraction/diskcache.php)? Just pay attention to the section "CACHE CONTENT"... The output cache file looks like:

```
<?php
$value = <<<FILEINFO_26
a:13:{s:4:"f_id";i:26;s:6:"f_hash";s:32:"d07288e848cc6219b7a793b0532f8fed";s:11:"f_extension";s:3:"jpg";s:6:"f_name";s:7:"214.jpg";s:6:"f_size";i:12902;s:10:"f_duration";N;s:6:"f_mime";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:11:"f_os_compat";N;s:9:"f_version";s:4:"NULL";s:14:"f_architecture";s:2:"32";s:7:"f_extra";N;s:11:"f_timestamp";i:1276516112;s:12:"f_dimensions";a:2:{s:5:"width";s:3:"180";s:6:"height";s:3:"227";}}
FILEINFO_26;

$is_array = 1;    

$ttl = 0; 
?>
```

It uses serialize() and can also store cache in Db... Source [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/persephone/source/browse/sources/kernel/cache.php).

Comment: ADDENDUM: I answered like this because asker's first sentence was "I want to store arrays in file.", so here you go... Store it anywhere, file, Db, memcached.